# In web-mode: how can I identify matching tags?

Tags: web-mode

I'm using *web-mode* for PHP.

When I'm navigating through tags, it would be helpful if I could visually identify a matching half of a tag pair.

Something like this exists for other modes, so I'm guessing that there's a way to configure for this in *web-mode*?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by enabling [`web-mode-enable-current-column-highlight`](https://web-mode.org) user option.

```el
(setq web-mode-enable-current-column-highlight t)
```

[image: Pair of tags highlighted]